# How to grant user DB_Owner on all SharePoint 2013 databases

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, sql

For many admin tasks for SharePoint 2013 using PowerShell you need to have DB_Owner for all SharePoint databases. The Add-SPShellAdmin command no longer granted DB_Owner to the SharePoint databases, instead grants the user the "SharePoint_Shell_Access" role.

I want to run a scheduled task that will automatically add a list of users as DB_Owner to all of the SharePoint database.

How can this be done.

Comment: i think it is still working, i tested and i have the permission to run powershell against my DBs? what operation /task you want to perfrom

Comment: This is not true, dbowner is not needed as sharepoint shell access gives the correct permission to use powershell against sharepoint databases. Any specific powershell cmdlts you are thinking about?

Comment: I had problems with Move-SPSite (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328.aspx#Section3 and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/4d78380e-c698-4445-828a-aec656f27c86/movespsite-needs-sql-dbowner-permissions-but-addspshelladmin-does-not-grant-dbowner-?forum=sharepointadmin )and Restore-SpSite  .

Answer (score 3):

You can use the script to give specific users the db_owner role. Don't forget to dd all users to users.txt.

```
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(‘Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo’) | out-null

    $Users = get-content c:\users.txt
Foreach ($User in $Users){

    $InstanceName = ""
    $NewOwnerLoginName = $user;

    $smosvr = New-Object (‘Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server’) $InstanceName
    $agent = $smosvr.JobServer;

    $agent.Jobs | % {
        $_.set_OwnerLoginName($NewOwnerLoginName);
        $_.Alter();
        }
```

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @BennySkogberg Updated the answer

Comment: @CitizenDB Removed the notice, and upvoted. Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer the specific question related to SharePoint databases.

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
###Public Variables
$SQLServer = "Server\Instance" 
$MyUser = "domain/account"
$spDatabases = Get-SPDatabase

####Private Variables
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Integrated Security = True" 

$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

ForEach($spDatabase in $spDatabases)
{
    $SQLDBName = $spDatabase.Name   
    $SqlQuery = "use $SQLDBName; ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [$MYUSER];"
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
    $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
}

$SqlConnection.Close()
```